# Workbench problem in android

Tags: android, metadata, workbench

I copy my workbench all project folders except two project from another location D: drive, but there was created a problem, when I ran the Eclipse.Then I did the same job reverse,but it is necessary to set-- window->> preferences->> location of path  of android SDK, why?. And I have not restore my previous all project in to eclipse project explore section.

Now, when I run  eclipse the after the import new archive file, then I have faced just like picture red sign occurs my eclipse.
[image]

**NOTE:** I have copy .metadata folder as well.

**My Problem**[image]

It is necessary again add google mobile add to my project?

Comment: Please check the "Problems" view and tell us which is the specific problem.

Comment: @Dimitris, please see the my problem picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer, I suppose that you have to check your build path and set the proper location for your libs.

Answer (score 0):

do you have import the projects to your workspace or just copied them?
if you've just copied them try to clear the workspace (do **NOT** delete your projects on your drive, just remove it from the workbench) and import the projects again (right click in package explorer -> import -> general -> existing projects into workspace).

it's difficult to say what is wrong without any error logs.